# Core Data. How to build "NSPredicate ... argumentArray" with array of NSManagedObjects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have 2 NSManagedObjects entities: VNSource <*--> VNDataChart (using a SQLite backend iOS).
After some user's activities I have NSArray with selected Charts - listChartToDownload (contains VNDataChart objects).

I want to build predicate to filter all records in VNSource according objects in listChartToDownload.
I was successful with result array of VNSource objects by iterating  fetch request for each objects in listChartToDownload. But it seems to me that you have more effective way.

I try execute this code below, but result is false -  only one VNSource-object in arrayRequest (should be > 30).
Could you explane my mistakes?

```
NSFetchRequest *localRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];  
localRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"VNSource" inManagedObjectContext:context];  
localRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"resolution" ascending:YES]];  

localRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichChart = %@" argumentArray: listChartToDownload];
localRequest.fetchBatchSize = 100;
arrayRequest    = [context  executeFetchRequest:localRequest error:&error1];

[localRequest   release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood about your question, you should probably be using `whichChart IN %@` instead of `whichChart = %@`.

And also, you should probably just be doing:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichChart IN %@", listChartToDownload]
```

Comment: Unfortunately "whichChart IN %@" does not work :(  

'*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[VNDataChart countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d5ad50'

UPDATE: I'm sorry, forget about argumentArray. Thank you in advance!